# Ajax POST throwing 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I creates an Popup in asp.net core application to create and edit new book by using Ajax, jQuery and bootstrap but When I insert data in this form and post, this error appears 500 Internal Server Error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwBMX.png)

this my function in Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddOrEdite(int id, BookViewModel bookViewModel)
    {
       

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (id == 0)
            {
                string fileName = string.Empty;
                if (bookViewModel.File != null)
                {
                    string uploads = Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath, "uploads");
                    fileName = bookViewModel.File.FileName;
                    string fullPath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileName);
                    bookViewModel.File.CopyTo(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));
                    bookViewModel.Book.imageURL = fileName;
                }
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    bookViewModel.Authors = _authorRepository.GetAll();
                    return View(bookViewModel);
                }
                Book book = new Book
                {
                    Bookid = bookViewModel.Book.Bookid,
                    Title = bookViewModel.Book.Title,
                    price = bookViewModel.Book.price,
                    Authorid = bookViewModel.Book.Authorid,
                    Borrowerid = bookViewModel.Book.Borrowerid,
                    Author = bookViewModel.Book.Author,
                    Borrower = bookViewModel.Book.Borrower,
                    imageURL = fileName
                };
                _bookRepository.Create(bookViewModel.Book);
            }
            else
            {
            
                bookViewModel.Authors = _authorRepository.GetAll();
                _bookRepository.Update(bookViewModel.Book);
            }


            return Json(new { isValid = true, html = GlobalClass.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_ViewAllBook", _context.Books.ToList()) });
        }


        return Json(new { isValid = false, html = GlobalClass.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "AddOrEdit", bookViewModel) });
    }
```

this my function in site.js

```js
    jQueryAjaxPost = form => {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (res) {
                if (res.isValid) {
                    $('#view-all').html(res.html)
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                    $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                    $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
                }
                else
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(res.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
        return false;
    } catch (x) {
        console.log(x)
    }}
```

```html
@model BookViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="row orderForm">
    <form asp-controller="Book" asp-action="AddOrEdite" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Book.Bookid" />


        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Book.Author" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Book.Authorid,
                                       new SelectList(Model.Authors.Select(x => new { Value = x.AuthorId, Text = x.Name }), "Value", "Text"), "Select an author",
                                       htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control border-input" })
                <span asp-validation-for="Book.Author" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 center">
                <a class="btn btn-primary center" style="width:100%" asp-controller="Author" asp-action="Create">Create an author</a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Book.Title" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input asp-for="Book.Title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter book title" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Book.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Book.price" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div>
                        <input asp-for="Book.price" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter book title" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Book.price" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="File" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <input type="file" asp-for="File" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Image of the book" />
                <span asp-validation-for="File" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group col-md-12">
                <input class="btn btn-success center-block" type="submit" value="Create" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

this is my model

```
    public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Bookid { get; set; }
    [Required,MinLength(2),MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public string imageURL { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public int Authorid { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public int ? Borrowerid { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Borrower { get; set; }


}
```

this is my view model

```
  public class BookViewModel
{
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

can anyone help me please :( ?

Comment: Hi, please post your codes of `form` and the detail of error info.  500 means Server Error. You could focus on controller and debug step by step.

Comment: @Lightman 
<div class="row orderForm">
    <form asp-controller="Book" asp-action="AddOrEdite" onsubmit="return jQueryAjaxPost(this);">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Book.Bookid" />

    </form>

Comment: That's all codes of `<form>`? You can update to question.

Comment: @Lightman I updated my question

Comment: Hi, @Mostafa Gamal, please let us know if you have  updated information on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get null when use `bookViewModel.Book` in my opinion.

```
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        if (id == 0)
        {
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            if (bookViewModel.File != null)
            {
                string uploads = Path.Combine(hosting.WebRootPath, "uploads");
                fileName = bookViewModel.File.FileName;
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(uploads, fileName);
                bookViewModel.File.CopyTo(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));
                 
                // got null when bookViewModel.Book
                //bookViewModel.Book.imageURL = fileName;
                  if(bookViewModel.Book != null)
                     bookViewModel.Book.imageURL = fileName;
                 
            }
           ...
```

From the codes, I can't see `id` in `form`. You could try codes of `controller` below.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddOrEdite(BookViewModel bookViewModel)
{
   

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        if (bookViewModel.Book.Bookid == 0) // or bookViewModel.id
        {
```

Comment: If you need some further help. Post codes of your models.

Comment: i update my question and insert my models and view models

Comment: Hi, @Mostafa Gamal, I failed to run your code and updated the answer from experience. I strongly suggest you could debug your controller to locate the exception.